# How to execute remote code in PHP

Tags: php

I'm simply attempting to execute remote PHP code locally.

To put it simply, I have an external script hosted on xxx.com/code.txt - and then want to have my internal system load that code in PHP. I tried using `file_get_contents()` but I don't think this is the right method of doing so.

I also tried using `include()`, but it seems that most PHP configurations have the http wrapper disabled. So in that case, how can I, using PHP check to see if the server has `allow_url_include` enabled or not because my script relies on loading the external code, or at least having a if function to check if `allow_url_include` is enabled or not.

Comment: PHP is executed remotely.  If you're including it via your browser remotely you're just getting its output.

Comment: Well, usually you get your remote, hold the device button down (tv, cable, sat), have the code handy, until the power button blinks three times, then punch in the cod- Oh, you mean *programming code*.

Comment: `include($url)` is equivalent to `eval(file_get_contents($url))`, assuming you have at least `allow_url_fopen` enabled. It's also a really bad idea, and you should restructure your code to transmit data rather than PHP code if you have even half a chance.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve code injection with PHP? Do not do it. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection

Comment: okay @IMSoP I know it is a bad idea to `allow_url_fopen` and I don't want to do this actually. Is there anything else that can be handy for this? I mean validating the code with signatures on the client side before execution.

Comment: @SyedFahad I'm not entirely sure what you're asking ("anything else" is very broad) but it sounds like you might have a new question you want to ask, which should be on a new page, not in the comments here. Try to explain what you're trying to achieve, not how you're attempting to do it - what is the underlying problem which you have decided storing code on one server and executing it on another would be the solution to?

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
function get_data($url)
{
   $ch = curl_init();
   $timeout = 5;
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   echo $data;
   curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
}
```

You can call this function like this

```
$response = get_data('http://yoursite.com/code.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

To kinda safely import code you could:

- make a php script which requires a hash (big big big hash) and put it on the server you want to connect to.
- You can then @file_get_contents() that php file with the hash in the url
- That script accepts the hash, imports a file (whichever you want) and returns it.

But as they all said, if it's PHP you want to execute think twice.

And if this does not convince you at least don't do it plain text but encrypt it or something (SSL is something, but blowfish with a two sided key would be better) and an allowed IP system.

The point is that you want to control the gateways, not make it open to all.

Comment: You seem to be concentrating on not serving code to untrusted clients (although just making the URL long and hard to guess by adding a hash is a pretty poor way to do that), but the much much bigger problem is not executing code from an untrusted source.

Comment: You are right. But I was under the impression that he at least controlled both sides which nulls that statement in my answer. Non the less, you are right like I stated in the answer "if it's PHP you want to execute think twice". So yeah.

Comment: Yep, its PHP and that's why I am here to get your valuable help :) Okay, I am thinking to create private and public keys and pass it upon the code include, after verifying the keys, the code will execute on client side else ignore it.

Comment: If you're dead set on doing it, you should at least create a sandbox. I don't exactly how to do it, but Symphony (and thus Laravel) has a nice one.